# joining two columns, display in merged columns becomes null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I am going to use in one of my stored procs. Specs dictate that, in the table, there should are 3 parts of an address, but there are going to be merged into one column: AddressLine1 which is the Street, AddressLine2 which is the Subdivision/, and AddressLine3 which is the City/State/Province. out of all these 3 fields, only AddressLine1 is mandatory, the other 2 can be left NULL. here is my code joining the 3 address fields into one:

```
(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine1  + ' ' + tb_TransactionName.AddressLine2 + ' ' + tb_TransactionName.AddressLine3) as 'Address'
```

Given that, I have entered text in the AddressLine1. but whenever I run the query, the Address column displays NULL. The moment i don't add up the 3 address fields and display only AddressLine1, the text under the AddressLine1 column appears in the results. For other info, the table tb_Transaction is left-joined to another table tb_TransactionDetails:

```
FROM (tb_TransactionType inner join tb_TransactionDetails 
    on tb_TransactionType.TxnTypeCode = tb_TransactionDetails.TxnType)
    LEFT JOIN tb_TransactionName on tb_TransactionDetails.TxnID = tb_TransactionName.TxnID
```

any idea what could be the possible problem as to why the merged column displays NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet one of the columns you are joining are with NULL value, which makes the result NULL.

try this:

```
(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine1  + ' ' + ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine2, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine3, '')) as 'Address'
```

Comment: exactly. AddressLine2 and AddressLine3 can be set to null, as they are not mandatory. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
(ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine1,'')  + ' ' +
 ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine2,'') + ' ' +
 ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine3,'') as 'Address'
```